# How to make a htaccess selective redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

So, I'd like to redirect all urls such as

```
domain.com/bang
```

to

```
domain.com/process.php?id=bang
```

EXCEPT

when I have a specific one

```
domain.com/specific
```

I want it to change to

```
domain.com/specific.php
```

This should be quite easy but for some reason it has been giving me way too much trouble. For example, I really do not understand why this wouldn't work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)specific$ ./specific.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ ./process.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite conditions only apply to the immediately following rule, so you either need to duplicate your conditions, or move them so they are applied to your last rule, as that's the one that really needs it. The `^(.+)/?$` regex will match anything, including `specific.php` and `process.php`.

Try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^specific$ /specific.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /process.php?id=$1 [L]
```